# Is it possible to change the left drawable of a Button in Selector xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a left drawable assigned to a button as well as a background drawable. I want to supply a selector so that when a user presses/focuses/disables the button, its appearance changes. The image I am using for the left drawable is a red "x".

I would like this to swap out with a gray "X" while the button is pressed or disabled. Is this possible using a selector?

Here is what I tried (which works for the border/background image, but not for the left drawable (obviously).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
      android:state_enabled="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/GrayBorder" 
      android:drawableLeft="@drawable/GrayRemove"/>
  <item
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/GrayBorder" 
      android:drawableLeft="@drawable/GrayRemove" />
  <item
      android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_enabled="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/GrayBorder" 
      android:drawableLeft="@drawable/GrayRemove" />
  <item
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/BlackBorder"
       android:drawableLeft="@drawable/Remove"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: @ theMothaShip create a separate selector and set that as the leftdrawable.

Comment: @Varun I feel silly that I didn't think to do that in the first place... Thanks!

Comment: @Varun Worked like a charm, submit it as an answer and I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a separate selector and try setting that as the `drawableLeft` on your `Button`.

Comment: Can you explain this more? Not sure I understand.

Comment: In the question, OP has a `selector` set as the background and had another icon as the `leftDrawable` on the `Button` which did not reflect selection states. The solution is to not use a simple icon as the `leftDrawable` but instead create a `selector` drawable (StateListDrawable) and use that as the `leftDrawable`. If you would like to know more about about the `StateListDrawable`, follow this link to the official doc - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList