# Change drawableleft in button selector

Tags: android

I found this Q&A [Is it possible to change the left drawable of a Button in Selector xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454845/is-it-possible-to-change-the-left-drawable-of-a-button-in-selector-xml) and it doesn't work for me. I tried this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_rounded_button" android:drawableLeft="@drawable/aj_share_button_drawableleft" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_rounded_button_frame" android:drawableLeft="@drawable/aj_share_button_drawableleft" />
</selector>


<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/aj_share_button_white_icon" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/aj_share_button_blue_icon" />
</selector>
```

Set selector like this:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
android:background="@drawable/aj_share_button_state"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/aj_share_button_drawableleft" />
```

Can somebody tell me how to make this works?

Comment: explain more how it does not work for you, and if needed share some code

Comment: I didn't understand answer "Create a separate selector and try setting that as the drawableLeft on your Button." I was trying to set separate selector in selectors item drawable left. No I'm figured out that I needed to set selector like this: <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:background="@drawable/aj_share_button_state"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/aj_share_button_drawableleft" />

Comment: have you defined widht&height ?? post whole xml?? only `android:drawableLeft` not working or whole button is not showing ?

Comment: Here is the hole xml   <Button
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_ontent"
        android:background="@drawable/aj_share_button_state"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/aj_share_button_drawableleft"
        android:text="@string/share_button_text"
        android:textColor="@drawable/aj_share_button_text" />

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest:
Your button xml:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:background="@drawable/selector_aj_share_button_state"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/selector_aj_share_button_drawableleft"
/>
```

selector_aj_share_button_drawableleft.xml (in your drawable folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/aj_share_button_white_icon"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/aj_share_button_white_icon" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/aj_share_button_white_icon" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/aj_share_button_blue_icon"/>
</selector>
```

It works with left drawable now. Try to do the same thing with selector_aj_share_button_state. Hope it helps!