# Is this possible to change TextView Drawable left image on hover effect

Tags: android, textview, drawable, android-selector

Before posting it here I was googled a lot but nothing is found.
My problem is I have a textview in one of my activity xml file with drawable left icon on it,See below -

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edit_profile_tv"
        style="@style/style_large_text.black"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_edit"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_next"
        android:text="@string/profile_setting" />
```

Now I want to change drawable left and drawable right icon of textview when textview is clicked.

I used selector for applying hover effect on any view, but not getting any way to change drawable left and right icon on hover effect.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please tell me ..do you need hover effect or ontouch effect?

Comment: when user click my textview I need to change drawable left and right images.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the left drawable of a Button in Selector xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454845/is-it-possible-to-change-the-left-drawable-of-a-button-in-selector-xml)